# take some images stored manualy in firebase storage and use it in my react native app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I'm trying to learn react native by doing some practical. The problem I have is that I'm not able to use the images I stored in Firebase storage. O just don't know how to do it, so I hope you can help me.

I tried this from the official documentation, but is not working and is saying that await can only be used in async function.

```
 import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';

  const url = await storage()
    .ref('images/profile-1.png')
    .getDownloadURL();
```

Comment: Did you search for the error message you got?

Comment: yes boss the error message was await can only be used in async fuction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run this code in a context where you can't use `await`, you can always use `then()` to accomplish the same:

```
  storage()
    .ref('images/profile-1.png')
    .getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
      console.log(url);
    });
```

Just keep in mind that the `url` is only usable from inside the `then` callback or from code that you call from there. Trying to use `url` from elsewhere will result in it not existing, or not being initialized. To learn more about that, also see [Why Does Firebase Lose Reference outside the once() Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40688268/why-does-firebase-lose-reference-outside-the-once-function/40688890#40688890)

Comment: thanks you sir im going to try it and and i will let you know for the result

Comment: thank you very much Mr Frank van Puffelen it work for me perfectly

Comment: may god bless you

Comment: now the remaining problem if you please want to help me is how can i use this profile-1.png image in my code  i tried  <Image source=require('profile-1.png')/> not not able to take this image from  Firebase storage