# How to save a result from a Firestore query into a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection named "users". I need to save 1 user and all data with this user.

```
const user= db.collection('users').where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', presenceObj.data().UserId).get();
```

But does not receive the data.

```
console.log(user.data().name);
```

Doesn't write anything on console.

Comment: The problem is typically not that the variable isn't saved, but that your `console.log(user.data().name)` runs before the data is loaded. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40688268/why-does-firebase-lose-reference-outside-the-once-function/40688890#40688890 for an explanation and how to deal with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is typically not that the variable isn't saved, but that your `console.log(user.data().name)` runs before the data is loaded.

See [Why Does Firebase Lose Reference outside the once() Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40688268/why-does-firebase-lose-reference-outside-the-once-function/40688890#40688890) for an explanation and how to deal with this.

If you're running in a modern environment, you can [use `async` and `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) to make the code a bit more readable:

```
const user= await db.collection('users')...;
```

But this is just syntactic sugar, and the data is still loaded asynchronously behind the scenes, so I highly recommend spending some time to read up on that.