# Fetch data from Cloud Firestore and store it in a constant

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

```
const set = firebase.firestore().collection("workoutExercises").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get()
  console.log(set)
```

**Terminal:**

```
Promise {
  "_U": 0,
  "_V": 0,
  "_W": null,
  "_X
}
```

**Firestore document:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwi8f.png)

Hello everyone, I am trying to get data from Cloud Firestore, when I run the code it only returns the code in the Terminal above,  I am using React Native, and the goal is to store the Array `set` from Firebase to the const `set` in the screen.
Thank You

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save a result from a Firestore query into a javascript variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67906378/how-to-save-a-result-from-a-firestore-query-into-a-javascript-variable)

Comment: How are you instantiating firebase and firestore?

Comment: @MattU no really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase calls like this are *asynchronous*, meaning they don't return immediately. In Javascript, you can deal with this in a couple of different ways, using `async/await` or `Promises`.

Here's an example using a `Promise`:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("workoutExercises").doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).get()
.then(document => {
  console.log(document.data());
})
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```

The question/answer linked in the comments shows you how to do this with `async/await`.

Comment: thank you, it works, but it returns in the terminal a bunch of data I don't need, I only need the values in the Firebase document so I can use them in a Flatlist.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect this. Also, see documentation at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document

Comment: I've struggling with this for days, thank you very much