# Data not working in global scope but in local scope

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to make an e-commerce website and in that almost all things are done except for the database part. In which I have to fetch the data from firebase and use it in the products section.
I have fetched the data in local variables, however I want to store the data in a global scoped object, but it is not working.
So what I basically want is I want to fetch the data from firebase(DONE) and store it in global scope object(PENDING) so that I can use this object in other .js files.
Any kind of idea/advice/help/suggestion in more than welcomed!!
Thanks in advance!

This is my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/kumartanwar123/gseh4coq/

**OR**

```
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.7/firebase-app.js";
import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.7/firebase-analytics.js";
// GLOBAL VARIABLES
var name, images, prices;
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "--",
  authDomain: "--",
  databaseURL: "--",
  projectId: "round-device-336118",
  storageBucket: "round-device-336118.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "--",
  appId: "--",
  measurementId: "--",
};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
class firebase_class {
  constructor(Images, Prices, Name) {
    this.Images = Images;
    this.Prices = Prices;
    this.Name = Name;
  }
}
// FIREBASE DATA FETCH
firebase
  .database()
  .ref("Practice")
  .on("value", function (all_data) {
    all_data.forEach(function (current_data) {
      name = Object.keys(current_data.val().Name).map(
        (keys) => current_data.val().Name[keys]
      );
      //In this if I use console.log(name) then it is working just fine, but not in outside the function.
      images = Object.keys(current_data.val().Images).map(
        (keys) => current_data.val().Images[keys]
      );
      prices = Object.keys(current_data.val().Prices).map(
        (keys) => current_data.val().Prices[keys]
      );
    });
  });
let firebase_object = new firebase_class(images, prices, name);
```

Comment: Variables declared in a module are not global, they're local to the module they're declared in.

Comment: I can use import/export for that case, however as it stands I can't even use the variables in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not *where* you access the database, but *when* you access it.

Data is loaded from Firebase (and pretty much all modern cloud APIs) asynchronously, and your main code (and thus the `let firebase_object = new firebase_class(images, prices, name)`) continues to execute while the data is loaded. Then when the data is available, your callback is invoked with it and it sets `images`, `prices`, and `name`.

And code that needs the data from Firebase has to be inside the callback, or be called from there. So:

```
// FIREBASE DATA FETCH
firebase
  .database()
  .ref("Practice")
  .on("value", function (all_data) {
    all_data.forEach(function (current_data) {
      name = Object.keys(current_data.val().Name).map(
        (keys) => current_data.val().Name[keys]
      );
      //In this if I use console.log(name) then it is working just fine, but not in outside the function.
      images = Object.keys(current_data.val().Images).map(
        (keys) => current_data.val().Images[keys]
      );
      prices = Object.keys(current_data.val().Prices).map(
        (keys) => current_data.val().Prices[keys]
      );
    });
    // 
    let firebase_object = new firebase_class(images, prices, name);
    ... any use of firebase_object should be here too
  });
```

Also check out:

- [Why Does Firebase Lose Reference outside the once() Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40688268/why-does-firebase-lose-reference-outside-the-once-function/40688890#40688890)

Comment: You will need to ensure the code in that function executes *after* your `on` handler. For example, you could call the function inside the callback after the `let firebase_object = new firebase_class(images, prices, name);` executes. I also showed other ways in my answer to the question I linked.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, and I tried to use promise, but I realised that on() takes two arguments and if not then it gives some error like "Query.on failed: Was called with 1 argument. Expects at least 2."

Comment: Calling `on` attaches a permanent listener, and its callback can be invoked multiple times, so there's no way for that to return a promise. If you only care about a value once, use `once` or `get` which already return a promise.