# Firebase Functions Global Variable Not Updating

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am making external API calls in my Firebase Cloud Functions in which I need to pass an authentication token. Instead of generating a new authentication token every time I need to make the external API call, I store the API token when I don't have one, and as long as it's valid, I want to re-use it for further requests.

I have created a global variable `globalToken` for this purpose. However, when I call my function to retrieve a token and re-use if possible, an existing token is never re-used as the function always seems to say that the global variable is set to null.

```
let globalToken = null

async function getToken() {
    if(!!globalToken) {
        console.log('was able to re-use already-existing token')
        return globalToken
    }
    console.log(`no existing token could have been reused because globalToken was set to: ${globalToken}`) // always displays globalToken as null
    const newToken = axios.post(...)
    globalToken = newToken
    console.log(`updated globalToken to: ${globalToken}`) // correctly prints out the new token
    return newToken
}

exports.getToken = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const token = await getToken()
    return ({ token: token })
})
```

If the logs confirm that the global variable is being changed at the time of new token retrieval, why do the subsequent runs read the global variable as `null` value instead of the already-retrieved token?

Comment: I see no other reads of `globalToken` except the `console.log`, but most likely your other code is reading `globalToken` before you set it. Only if the code is guarded by an `await` call or ` `then()` clause will it be waiting for the data that is asynchronously loading. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40688268/why-does-firebase-lose-reference-outside-the-once-function/40688890#40688890

Comment: It's not. When I say that `globalToken` is read as `null`, it's because the log statement outputs it as that - not because some other function not listed in my post retrieves it as null.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It's a bit unclear from the code you shared, but I expect you also need to `await` the result when you call `axios.post(...)`.