# Statements executing out-of-order with Firebase and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I have a constructor for *ChatRoom* that looks like this:

```
class ChatRoom {
    constructor(title, userA, userB, advertId, onComplete, fromRef) {

        this.members = [{
            userId: userA.userId,
            username: userA.username || '',
            photo: userA.photo || '',
        }, {
            userId: userB.userId,
            username: userB.username || '',
            photo: userB.photo || ''
        }]; 

        this.createdAt = Date.now()
        this.advertId = advertId
        this.isRemoved = false;
        if (_.isEmpty(fromRef)) {
            this._sendTofirebase(onComplete)
        } else {
            this.chatRoomRef = fromRef
        }

    }
```

The function of interested is called *sendTofirebase* which is places on the 3rd line from the bottom. The function has this code:

```
_sendTofirebase(onComplete) {
        this._checkDuplicateChat((isDuplicate) => {
          if (isDuplicate)
          {
                var error = new ChatRoomError("Chat room was not created")
                error.code = '409_DUPLICATE_RECORD_FOUND'
                throw error
          }
          // create chat room reference in firebase
          this.chatRoomRef = firebase().ref('ChatRooms/').push({
              title: this.title,
              advertId: this.advertId,
              members: this.members,
              createdAt: this.createdAt,
              isRemoved: this.isRemoved,
          }, onComplete);
          var chatKey = this.chatRoomRef.key
          // create user chat reference in firebase
          this.UserChatRef = firebase().ref("UsersChat").child(this.members[0].userId).child(chatKey).set({"lastModified":Date.now(), "lastMessage" : ''}, (err) => {
              if (err) {
                  throw new ChatRoomError(err)
              }
          });
      
          // create user chat reference in firebase
          this.UserChatRef = firebase().ref("UsersChat").child(this.members[1].userId).child(chatKey).set({"lastModified":Date.now(), "lastMessage" : ''}, (err) => {
              if (err) {
                  throw new ChatRoomError(err)
              }
          });
        });
      }
```

The function *sendTofirebase* will create a ChatRoom object and send it to the realtime database in Firebase. This works fine. However, in this function, I call another function called *checkDuplicateChat()* which is supposed to query all the *ChatRoom* objects and check if any *ChatRoom* object contains members with the same ID as the one being created. Essentially it checks for duplicate *ChatRooms*.

The issue here is that in the *sendTofirebase()* function, the entire function seems to execute, which creates the ChatRoom, before the *checkDuplicateChat()* can finish executing and throw an error that a duplicate has been found.

I am aware that querying databases is an asynchronous operation, I attempted to use async/await but it didn't work, I also attempted to nest the rest of the *sendTofirebase()* inside the callback of *checkDuplicateChat()* but it also did not work. I have been scratching my head over this for a couple of days, so i'd greatly appreciate any help

P.S the code for the *checkDuplicateChat()* function is here:

```
_checkDuplicateChat(onComplete) {
        const userA_ID = this.members[0].userId
        const userB_ID = this.members[1].userId
        this.chatRoomRef = firebase().ref('ChatRooms')
        var foundRoom = false
        this.chatRoomRef.once('value', (chatSnapshot) => {
             chatSnapshot.forEach((snapshot) => {
                var snap = snapshot.val()
                if ((snap.members[0].userId == userA_ID && snap.members[1].userId == userB_ID)
                    || (snap.members[0].userId == userB_ID && snap.members[1].userId == userA_ID)) {
                        foundRoom = true;
                    }
            })
            onComplete(foundRoom);
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the expected behavior, since `_checkDuplicateChat` perform asynchronous work (just like `_sendTofirebase` itself does). You will need to pass *a separate* callback into `_checkDuplicateChat`, just like (but separate from) the one you pass into `_sendTofirebase` already:

```
_sendTofirebase(onComplete) {
  this._checkDuplicateChat((isDuplicate) => { // 
    // TODO: create the room based on the value of isDuplicate

    // create chat room reference in firebase
    this.chatRoomRef = firebase().ref('ChatRooms/').push({
        title: this.title,
        advertId: this.advertId,
        members: this.members,
        createdAt: this.createdAt,
        isRemoved: this.isRemoved,
    }, onComplete);

    var chatKey = this.chatRoomRef.key
    // create user chat reference in firebase
    this.UserChatRef = firebase().ref("UsersChat").child(this.members[0].userId).child(chatKey).set({"lastModified":Date.now(), "lastMessage" : ''}, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            throw new ChatRoomError(err)
        }
    });

    // create user chat reference in firebase
    this.UserChatRef = firebase().ref("UsersChat").child(this.members[1].userId).child(chatKey).set({"lastModified":Date.now(), "lastMessage" : ''}, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            throw new ChatRoomError(err)
        }
    });
  });
}
```

For this to work, your `_checkDuplicateChat` then needs to call its callback with the result of the asynchronous operation. When we also remove the duplicate data loading from that function, it ends up like this:

```
_checkDuplicateChat(onComplete) {
    const userA_ID = this.members[0].userId
    const userB_ID = this.members[1].userId
    this.chatRoomRef = firebase().ref('ChatRooms')
    val foundRoom = false
    this.chatRoomRef.on('value', (chatSnapshot) => {
         chatSnapshot.forEach((snapshot) => {
            var snap = snapshot.val()
            if ((snap.members[0].userId == userA_ID && snap.members[1].userId == userB_ID)
                || (snap.members[0].userId == userB_ID && snap.members[1].userId == userA_ID)) {
                    foundRoom = true;
                }
        })
        onComplete(foundRoom);
    })
}
```

Since you seem uncomfortable with asynchronous operations, I recommend reading up on those with:

- [Why Does Firebase Lose Reference outside the once() Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40688268/why-does-firebase-lose-reference-outside-the-once-function/40688890#40688890)
- the MDN documentation on [asynchronous JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous).

Also: a more effective structure for organizing chat rooms can be found in [Best way to manage Chat channels in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33540479/best-way-to-manage-chat-channels-in-firebase)

Comment: Hey, appreciate the sources and solution. However, when I implement your solution I lose reference to the _this._ operator for some reason. It keeps giving me _Cannot read property 'title' of undefined_ error. What could be a solution here?

Comment: That was already present in the code in your question. I changed it to use fat arrow functions (`=>`) everywhere.